# Concerns on file permissions

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a video file and I have commanded the server through htaccess to redirect when  requesting the file url. However, I wonder if someone remote can use php functions such as `file_get_contents` to access the video file since I have only one server and I am not sure whether remote servers can access to it. In my own server I can access to it. Yet I don't want others to access the video file unless authenticated by php.

Comment: Unless  they have access to your server, it can't be access using your website

Comment: If you're worried about remote attackers executing arbitrary php code on your webserver, accessing a video file is probably the least of your concerns.

Comment: You mean that the file get contents would only be successful if the server is the same as the video file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really do not want people to get that video why have it in public web folder? Just put it somewhere else and problem solved. What is the use case of this?

That said, if your redirect is working correctly, the file will not be served. `file_get_contents()` is still requesting the file from your webserver so it can't just magically ignore the redirect.

If you want to be able to download that file but prevent everyone else from doing it, put the file out of your www root and have a php script to retreive it. You can set up basic http authentication to prevent anyone accessing the php script.

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary")
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"myvideo.avi\""); 
echo file_get_contents("/directory/out/of/www/that/is/readable/by/www-data");
```